# How to pattern match on the type of the message received in F# akka.net?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, akka.net

Please see last edit.

Apologies for the newbie question. I am trying to implement something in F# using Akka.net. I'm very new to F# and I have only used Akka from Scala. Basically I am trying to implement something that's pretty easy in Scala, namely making an Actor do different things based on the type of message it receives.

My code is below and it's a slight modification of the hello world example lifted from the akka.net website. I believe a first problem with my code is that it does record pattern matching instead of type pattern matching, however I was unable to write a type match one without compilation errors... Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
open Akka.FSharp
open Actors
open Akka
open Akka.Actor

type Entries = { Entries: List<string>}

let system = ActorSystem.Create "MySystem"

let feedBrowser = spawn system "feedBrowser" <| fun mailbox -> 
    let rec loop() = actor {
        let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
        match msg with 
        | { Entries = entries} -> printf "%A" entries
        | _ -> printf "unmatched message %A" msg 
        return! loop()}
    loop()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    feedBrowser <! "abc"        // this should not blow up but it does

    system.AwaitTermination()

    0
```

Edit: the error is a runtime one, System.InvalidCastException, unable to cast object of type String to Entries.

Later edit: I got this to work with this change, downcasting to Object:

```
let feedBrowser = spawn system "feedBrowser" <| fun mailbox -> 
    let rec loop() = actor {
        let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
        let msgObj = msg :> Object
        match msgObj with 
        | :? Entries as e  -> printfn "matched message %A" e
        | _ -> printf "unmatched message %A" msg 
        return! loop()}
    loop()
```

Now these two lines work correctly

```
feedBrowser <! "abc"
feedBrowser <! { Entries = ["a"; "b"] }
```

the first one prints "unmatched message abc" and the second outputs the entries.

Is there a better way of going about this, without the cast? Does akka.net have something specifically for this case? 
Thank you.

Comment: You should specify what the error is.

Comment: I have edited the post and added the exception message.

Comment: Eh, you're passing `"abc"` – what do you expect? Maybe you want `feedBrowser (Entries(List([|"abc"|])))`? (Assuming that's not F#'s `list`, in which case `feedBrowser (Entries ["abc"])`.)

Comment: I am expecting it print "unmatched message abc", that is precisely the point, when it can not find a match.

Comment: But you are never casting - you probably have a warning about the `_` match never happening.  You need to use a type test pattern, not a record pattern

Comment: Yes, exactly; I've eventually figured that out and edited the post (10min before you sent the comment). I'm still hung up on the Scala way of doing things! There is still the question if I could avoid the cast to Object so I can do the type pattern matching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [Discriminated Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) (the Command type in this example). Then you can pattern match its options.

```
type Entries = { Entries: List<string>}

type Command = 
    | ListEntries of Entries
    | OtherCommand of string

let stack() = 

    let system = ActorSystem.Create "MySystem"

    let feedBrowser = spawn system "feedBrowser" <| fun mailbox -> 
        let rec loop() = actor {
            let! msg = mailbox.Receive()
            match msg with 
            | ListEntries { Entries = entries} -> printf "%A" entries
            | OtherCommand s -> printf "%s" s
            return! loop() }
        loop()
```

And to send the message you should use:

```
feedBrowser <! OtherCommand "abc"
feedBrowser <! ListEntries { Entries = ["a"; "b"] }
```

It's important to say that the send operator has the following signature:

```
#ICanTell -> obj -> unit
```

So, if you pass an message with a different type, like a string, it'll raise an exception.

Comment: Thank you. It is cleaner than the cast to Object.